# CakePHP and subquery

Tags: sql, cakephp

How can I write a SQL subquery using cake syntax?
I know how to code a simple query, but I can't handle subqueries.

This is the original query:

```
SELECT Assumption.id, Referee.id, Referee.first_name, Referee.second_name
FROM referees AS Referee
INNER JOIN (

    SELECT a.id, a.referee_id
    FROM assumptions a
    WHERE a.season_id =7
) AS Assumption ON Referee.id = Assumption.referee_id
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you didn't understand the syntax, this is the actual query:

```
$records = $this->Referee->find('all', array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'Assumption.id', 'Referee.id', 'Referee.first_name', 'Referee.second_name'
                    ),
                'joins' => array(
                    array(
                        'table' => 'assumptions',
                        'alias' => 'Assumption',
                        'type'  => 'INNER',
                        'foreignKey'    => false,
                        'conditions'    => array('Referee.id = Assumption.referee_id', 'Assumption.season_id = 7'),
                        ),
                ),
            )
        );
```

Which produces this query:

```
SELECT 
    `Assumption`.`id`,
    `Referee`.`id`,
    `Referee`.`first_name`,
    `Referee`.`second_name`
FROM `referees` AS `Referee`
INNER JOIN assumptions AS `Assumption`
    ON (`Referee`.`id` = `Assumption`.`referee_id` 
        AND `Assumption`.`season_id` = 7)
```

Which provide the results you are looking for.

Sample output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Assumption] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [season_id] => 7
                            [referee_id] => 1
                            [name] => SomeAssumpton
                        )

                )

            [Referee] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [first_name] => Ref
                    [second_name] => one
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: This produce simple query, that produce unusefull response. I should reproduce exactly that subquery.

Comment: I wrote the code for you since you could not understand the syntax. It will produce the results you are looking for.

Comment: If you want your EXACT subquery, the only other option you have is to use: `$this->Referee->query('{YOUR SUB-QUERY HERE}');` as CakePHP does not have a syntax for subqueries the way you are wanting to write them.

Answer (score 2):

cdburgess's answer is correct for this situation; it solves the problem in the simplest and most straightforward way.

That being said, when solving the generic question of performing a subquery, the Cookbook documents the [preferred solution to the subquery problem](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions).  It's not very elegant, but it's the way the guide says to do it.

Or you can simply be very careful and just do a $this->Model->query().

Comment: It's not correct if it doesn't answer the question.  Giving an un-related answer doesn't make the answer correct. If the question was, how do i query a relationship in cakephp, then that would be the correct answer.

Comment: Chuck Burgess most definitely answers the OP's question - his method even yields the correct results in a more efficient manner. No reason to be picky about whether it used a subquery if there's a better solution.

Comment: More than likely what his question says is just an example of the situation he's being presented.  The query would probably be more complex than that, like mine for example.  I have three models, a, b and c, a has a many to many with b which contains a type with a pivot table, and c has a many to one relationship with a. If I needed a report where type of c is a certain value, when it does the report it'll return duplicates, 1 for every relationship because it had to load it before checking the type.  A true subquery like he described could solve that, not the answer that Chuck said.

Answer (score 1):

so after what seemed like years (several hours) and reading cake source... if you want to simply type your subquery into your cake conditions...

it uses php stdClass not an array entry...  it will just dump your "value" into the query...

```
    $subquery = new stdClass();
    $subquery->type = "expression";
    $subquery->value = "Product.id IN (select product_id from product_categories where category_id='$category_id' or belongs_to='$category_id')";

    $options['conditions'][] = $subquery;  <- dump the class into your conditions array!
```

do normal query
$this->table->find('all', $options)

EXAMPLE: (normal cake with subquery quickfix)

```
    //only from my vendor
    $options['conditions']['collection_id'] = $vendor_id;

    //inner join to CollectionProduct
    $options['joins'][0] = array(
        "table" => "collection_products",
        "alias" => "CollectionProduct",
        "type"  => "INNER",
        "conditions" => array(
            "Product.id = CollectionProduct.product_id",
        ),
    );

    //show only from current category
    if ($category_id) {
        $subquery = new stdClass();
        $subquery->type = "expression";
        $subquery->value = "Product.id IN (select product_id from product_categories where category_id='$category_id' or belongs_to='$category_id')";
        $options['conditions'][] = $subquery;
    } else {
        //get 18 random items... no category selected?
        $options['limit'] = 18;
    }

    return $this->find('all', $options);
```

Comment: That's what happens behind the scenes, but the proper way to do it would be to follow [the instructions in the Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions).

Comment: if you goto your link and go down to "Sub-queries" you will see a huge overhead to generate the one line of sql shown above and this is short and sweet.  there are plenty of queries cake "can't" do.  If your doing multi-nested subqueries imagine how horrible the cookbook would be.

Comment: The only reason this method saves space is because the subquery was written explicitly.  The OP specifically stated they wanted to use cake methodology.  The shortest route if you don't care is to simply use $this->Model->query().  Agreed, the guide's method is long, but it doesn't help that the author of the example code didn't do the greatest job.

Comment: Only difference if you use query() directly you need to write the whole query not just an exception for the sub query.  I have updated the example with an example to show this.