# CakePHP - Building a Complex Query

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I have the following query I want to build using CakePHP. How should I go about this?

```
        SELECT
            `Artist`.`id`,
            CONCAT_WS(' ', `Person`.`first_name`, `Person`.`last_name`, `Person`.`post_nominal_letters`) AS `name`,
            `Portfolio`.`count`
        FROM
            `people` as `Person`,
            `artists` as `Artist`
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            (SELECT
                `Product`.`artist_id`,
                 COUNT(DISTINCT `Product`.`id`) AS `count`
            FROM
                `product_availabilities` AS `ProductAvailability`,
                `products` AS `Product`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                `order_details` AS `OrderDetail`
            ON
                `Product`.`id` = `OrderDetail`.`product_id`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                `orders` AS `Order`
            ON
                `Order`.`id` = `OrderDetail`.`order_id`
            WHERE
                `ProductAvailability`.`id` = `Product`.`product_availability_id`
            AND
                `Product`.`online` = true
            AND
                (`ProductAvailability`.`name` = 'For sale')
                OR
                    ((`ProductAvailability`.`name` = 'Sold') AND (DATEDIFF(now(),`Order`.`order_date`) <= 30))
            GROUP BY
                `Product`.`artist_id`)
        AS
            `Portfolio`
        ON
            `Artist`.`id` = `Portfolio`.`artist_id`
        WHERE
            `Artist`.`person_id` = `Person`.`id`
        AND
            `Artist`.`online` = true
        GROUP BY
            `Artist`.`id`
        ORDER BY
            `Person`.`last_name`, `Person`.`first_name`;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the model is Artist and It has a belongsTo Relationship with , then you could use the CakePHP ORM on this way and hasMany with Portfolio

first you mus distroy the relation between Artist and Portfolio

`$this->Artist->unbindModel(array('hasMany'=>array('Portfolio')))`;

and then Build the relations

```
$this->Artist->bindModel(array('hasOne'=>array('Portfolio')));
```

Finally you must create the other relationsships

```
$this->Artist->bindModel(array(
'belongsTo'=>array(
'Product'=>array(
 'clasName'=>'Product',
 'foreignKey'=> false,
 'conditions'=>'Product.id = Artist.product_id'
 ),
 'ProductAvaibility'=>array(
 'clasName'=>'ProductAvaibility',
 'foreignKey'=> false,
 'conditions'=>'ProductAvaibility.id = Product.product_avaibility_id'
 ),
 'OrderDetail'=>array(
 'clasName'=>'OrderDetail',
 'foreignKey'=> false,
 'conditions'=>'Product.id = OrderDetail.product_id'
 ),
 'Order'=>array(
 'clasName'=>'Order',
 'foreignKey'=> false,
 'conditions'=>'Order.id = OrderDetail.order_id'
 ),
)
));
```

Now, when the relationships are done, you could do your find

```
$this->Artist->find('all', array(
'conditions'=>array(
'Artist.online'=>true
),
'group'=>array(
'Artist.id'
),
'order'=>array(
'Person.last_name', 
'Person.first_name', 
)
))
```

I hope it could be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

You should place it in your model. If you haven't read yet, I suggest you to read about [skinny controllers and fat models](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2009/01/06/another-way-to-think-about-mvc/).

```
class YourModel extends AppModel {

    public function getArtistsAndPortfolioCounts() {
        return $this->query("SELECT ... ");
    }

}
```

So in your controller:

```
class ArtistsControllre extends AppController {
    public function yourAction() {
        debug($this->YourModel->getArtistsAndPortfolioCounts());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `Model::query()` method the best way to do this?

Comment: I think so, because this way you can cache and it is returned as close as $this->find() would.

Comment: Can you do it using subqueries, would this not be better for code maintenance?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `query` method, but that method is treated as a last resort, when `find` or any of the other convenience methods don't suffice.

But it's also possible to manually specify joins in the Cake `find` method, [see the cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html). I'm not entirely sure, but I believe nested joins are also supported. `CONCAT_WS` could just be called, with the relevant fields, in the `field` property of the find method.

Comment: CakePHP 2.0 has virtual fields where you can specify any SQL to be that field, including subqueries and CONCAT_WS

Comment: They're are also present in Cake 1.3, should you want to use "virtual fields": http://book.cakephp.org/view/1608/Virtual-fields

Comment: Surely you can't use virtualFields to get the `Portfolio.count` for each Artist?

Comment: There are indeed limitations and possible workarounds: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1608/Virtual-fields#Limitations-of-virtualFields-1642

Comment: As far as I can see you can't specify joins that use a subquery as shown in my SQL statement in the question...

Comment: You might be right. There is a Cake way of building subqueries (http://book.cakephp.org/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions), which is discussed further [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6839797/196750). But at this point I would probably use `query()`, for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to build that query using ORM. It will be a disaster in slow motion.

Instead you should try to do that request as "close to metal" as possible. I am not familiar with CakePHP's API ( as i tend to avoid it like black plague ), but you should be able to create a `Model` which is not related to ActiveRecord, and most likely have access to anything similar to PDO wrapper.  Use that to execute the query and map results to variables.

---

That said, you might want to examine your query ( you seem to have some compulsive *quoting sickness* ). One of improvements you could do would be stop using `id` columns in tables.

This whole setup could really benefit from creation of another column in Artists table : `portfolio_size`. Which you can update each time it should be changed. Yes , it would de-normalize your table, but it also will make this query trivial and blazing fast, with minor costs elsewhere.

---

As for names of columns, if table `Artists` has a id, then keep it in column `artist_id` , and if `Products` has a foreign key referring to `Artists.artist_id` then name it too `artist_id`. Same thing should have same name all over your database. This would additionally let you use in SQL `USING` statement. Here is a small example :

```
SELECT 
   Users.name
   Users.email
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN GroupUsers USING (user_id)
LEFT JOIN Groups USING (group_id)
WHERE Groups.name = 'wheel'
```

I assume that this query does not need explanation as it is a simple many-to-many relationship between users and groups.