# Convert sql statement to cakephp statment

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am using cakephp 2.1 and written sql statement as follows.

```
SELECT * FROM industry
LEFT JOIN movie ON movie.industry_id = industry.id
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(id) AS TID ,movie_id FROM trailer
        GROUP BY movie_id

      ) AS c ON c.movie_id = movie.id
LIMIT 0, 4;
```

where industry is "Industry" model, movie is "Movie" model and trailer is "Trailer" model and I have tried this one.

```
$options['joins'] = array(
        array(
            'table' => 'movies',
            'alias' => 'Movie',
            'type' => 'left',
            'conditions' => array('Industry.id = Movie.industry_id')), 
        array(
            'table' => 'movie_trailers',
            'alias' => 'Trailer',
            'type' => 'left',
            'conditions' => array('Trailer.movie_id = Movie.id')));

    $trailers = $this->Industry->find('all', $options);
```

So please suggest me to convert this statement to cakephp statement.

Comment: Have you searched the web or SO for this? Lots of links and resources... You should also post your attempts to doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL is a `join` with a `sub query`, while the Cake code is `join` only.

You can do a [sub query](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries) but I would look for a way to do it with a join only.

Given the lack of details in your question I cant help with a better query.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish with your query. But it looks like what you really want is the information about the four most recent trailers.

That being as it is, you can always just throw it all in the join:

```
$records = $this->Industry->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('Trailer.id', 'Industry.id', 'Industry.Name', 'Movie.id', 'Movie.name'),
    'limit' => 4,
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'movies',
            'alias' => 'Movie',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Movie.industry_id = Industry.id'
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'table' => '(SELECT MAX(id) As id, movie_id FROM trailers GROUP BY movie_id)',
            'alias' => 'Trailer',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Trailer.movie_id = Movie.id'
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

It will defeat the portability of the ORM because of the query thrown in the table of the join, but it works.

Here is another question that may be of use: [CakePHP and subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770032/cakephp-and-subquery)